# how to test java card applet in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, applet

I use [IntelliJ IDEA JavaCard Project Template](https://github.com/FractalizeR/IntelliJ-IDEA-Java-Card-Project-Template) to develop my java card applet. But how could I test my code if it is correct?

I know Esclipe has a Plugin named JCOP which can easily test the java card applet, but I love IntelliJ more...

There is another tool: [jcardsim](https://github.com/licel/jcardsim). Do anyone know how to use it in IntelliJ?

Comment: [jcardsim](https://github.com/licel/jcardsim) seems to be a simple (test) library. Just add it to your classpath (maven or gradle or manually) and use the provided classes as explained on the github page

Comment: I tried to read the jcardsim readme file. But I still don't know how to use it. Can you give a simple example used in Intellij?

Answer (score 1):

I made a similar project template for gradle: https://github.com/ph4r05/javacard-gradle-template

It is very similar to the template you use so migration should be really just copy-paste. It already contains a HelloWorld applet in the module `applet` and basic unit test in the module `tester`.

The project template uses JCardSim for the testing. Give it a try.

Template usage:

```
git clone https://github.com/ph4r05/javacard-gradle-template.git

cd javacard-gradle-template
git submodule init
git submodule update
```